# how to extract the timestamp(6) Datatype value of a column from a database to csv or display on console using Java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, resultset

I want to extract the timestamp(6) datatype value of a column from database using Java. I am not able to find any method in reaultset or resultsetmetadata which can help me with this.
When I am using timestamp/ time/ Date method in resultset, it's changing the format. I want to retrieve exact format of timestamp(6) for ex.: 01-JAN-0001 02.30.32.001001 PM

I would be grateful if someone could help me with the solution for this issue.

Comment: A timestamp does not have a format - it is stored internally as a series of bytes each representing the one part of the  year, month, day, hour, minute, second and fractional second components. When you retrieve it then the user interface you are using will perform an implicit conversion to a human readable format (typically using the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter) but this is not what is stored in the database or transmitted to your Java application. If you want it with a format then you will need to convert it to a string and specify how it should be formatted.

Comment: Please show the code you currently use, and exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the value with resultSet.getTimestamp() and convert it to a String in Java taking care not to loose the nanoseconds that are stored separately, but you can always convert it to a String in the database. For example with Oracle:

```
create table t1 (ts1 timestamp(6) default systimestamp);
insert into t1 select systimestamp from dual;
select to_char(ts1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.SSSSSSS') from t1;
```

Change the date format for your target audience. A timestamp is not stored in a certain format, it is always converted. It is just that your database and the Java objects have different defaults.

Comment: But rs.getTimestamp(int columnIndex).toString() converting the data like yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss:s format.

Comment: @SanketChandak Then don't use [`Timestamp.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString--), as documented it returns a very specific format, if you want something else, then you should use a date formatter (and I'd suggest you use `toLocalDateTime()` and apply the desired format using the `java.time` package.

Comment: Or a classic SimpleDateFormat. Just be sure to take care of the nanoseconds if you need them as they are not handled by default.